# How to break out of a loop in x seconds

Tags: lua

I am trying to modify a FiveM script and I am trying to break out of a loop in Lua after 4 seconds but I don't know how.

I don't know what I am doing and need some help.

```lua
Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    function drawscaleform(scaleform)
        scaleform = RequestScaleformMovie(scaleform)

        while not HasScaleformMovieLoaded(scaleform) do
            Citizen.Wait(0)
        end

        PushScaleformMovieFunction(scaleform, "SHOW_POPUP_WARNING")
        PushScaleformMovieFunctionParameterFloat(500.0)
        PushScaleformMovieFunctionParameterString("ALERT")
        PushScaleformMovieFunctionParameterString("~b~Peacetime Active")
        PushScaleformMovieFunctionParameterString("This Means No Priority Calls")
        PushScaleformMovieFunctionParameterBool(true)
        PushScaleformMovieFunctionParameterInt(0)
        PopScaleformMovieFunctionVoid()

        DrawScaleformMovieFullscreen(scaleform, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0)
    end

    while true do
        Citizen.Wait(0)
        drawscaleform("POPUP_WARNING")
    end
end)
```

I would like to break out of the `while true` after 4 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Most likely some combination of Lua’s `break` command, setting a condition on your while loop that more clearly communicates the loop’s intention (other than just while `true`...) and better using FiveM’s `Citizen.Wait()` function. The documentation for that function [here](https://docs.fivem.net/scripting-reference/runtimes/lua/functions/Citizen.Wait/) says the argument is the number of milliseconds to pause the current execution thread.

Take some time to understand these elements, the code you are trying to modify, and experiment. SO won’t just code for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a FiveM function `Citizen.SetTimeout` to call a function after a period has elapsed. Here is one (untested) way you could use it:

```
Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    function drawscaleform(scaleform)
    ...
    end

    local wait = true

    Citizen.SetTimeout(4000, function() wait = false end)

    while wait do
        Citizen.Wait(0)
        drawscaleform("POPUP_WARNING")
    end
end)
```